# https.createServer ignoring ca array

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I use the following options passed to https.createServer,

```
options =
    ca: splitca fs.readFileSync sslpaths.capath, encoding:'utf8'
    key: fs.readFileSync sslpaths.keypath, encoding:'utf8'
    cert: fs.readFileSync sslpaths.certpath
```

Where `splitca` just to splits the two pem blocks of the CA crt bundle file.  However sometime Chrome does not like this and when I load my domain it says that the certificate cannot be trusted.  Then sometimes it works just fine and shows two Comodo CA nodes coming from the addTrust root, followed by my servers certificate.  When I use `openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 -showcerts` I get the error 'unable to get local issuer certificate'.  When I remove the ca parameter completely then Chrome will still sometimes work, but openssl still does not have the two CA pem blocks in the certificate chain.  I am guessing that Chrome is doing its own lookup of the CA and caching the certs?

I also tried prepending the CA crt file to in front of my server crt file and before upgrading my nodejs (v0.12) I would get some kind of handshake sslv3 failure from openssl.  Now when I try with nodejs v5.0, I get **error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch** being thrown from nodejs.  Any help would be appreciated.